# Show the rational map is continuous on (complex) domain and range?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functional-analysis

[image]

So far I was trying to show that projections from domain into one coordinate function is continuous and then the product of these are continuous but I am not sure how to do this?

Secondly, does anyone know where this question is from like which book? I want to practice more of these types of questions but my lecturer is only providing a few.

Answer (score 0):

You were on the right path. A vector-valued function is continuous iff all its components are, ie: every projection on one of the axes of $\mathbb{C}^m$ is continuous. Have you ever seen this property?

Now, the proof comes down to showing that the ratio of two polynomials is continuous on its domain of definition :).

Also, can you please be more specific on the type of questions you're looking for? There are a lot of very good textbooks on real analysis but this depends on your level/interests :)